# 1994 Ford F150 coming back to life

Tags: engine, ford, f-150

After 5 years of standing, I'm fixing up my 1994 F-150. Replacing plugs and wondering if I should add some engine oil to the cylinders to ensure good compression and reduce friction on startup. Thanks for the help. Brian

Comment: `add some engine oil to cylinders` how are you going to add oil to the cylinders can you please elaborate this further?

Comment: @DhKo when the plugs are out, there are holes (!!) where you can inject the small amounts of ATF as explained.

Answer (score 3):

As Paulster2 stated, but before you put the spark plugs back in, spin the engine over on the starter and get the oil pumped around the system so it does not start as dry.

Over 5 years most of the oil will have drained out and a no-load spinning will at least help reduce the initial wear.

Answer (score 1):

Pull all the plugs out (old ones). Squirt some **automatic transmission fluid** into each cylinder (one or two squirts; don't over due it). Turn the engine over by hand (with a socket on the crankshaft bolt) two to three complete revolutions. Replace the spark plugs with the new ones (gapping only if required), using anti-seize on the threads and dielectric grease in the wire boots. Then start the engine using a freshly charged battery. You may see a little bit of white smoke on startup. This is due to the tranny fluid burning off.